# Is this a standard way to describe this random variable?

Tags: probability

People:

I am reading a paper on probability in which the authors describe a [real-valued] random variable $X$ as symmetric, with $-1 \leq X \leq 1$, $E(X)=0$,  and $E(X^2)=1$.  For non-probabilists like me out there, "symmetric" means what you probably think it means: for any $a<b$, $P(a<X<b)=P(-b<X<-a)$.  Of course the condition $E(X)=0$ is redundant, because $X$ is symmetric with $-1 \leq X \leq 1$.

The conditions above are equivalent to $X$ equaling $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2$.  I think the paper would be more readable if the authors had just described $X$ that way.  They use the above wording over and over again throughout the paper.

So my question is, is the way the authors describe $X$ standard in the probability world, or is it a sign that the authors overlooked something that should have been obvious and that maybe the paper is not so good?

Comment: Sinces $X$ is **real-valued**, it doesn't have to be an integer. Thus, $X$ has a probability distribution over $[-1,1]$, instead of over $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: @Ragnar: The distribution the OP describes is the only one with the correct variance.

Comment: @Stefan: It's hard to answer your question without actually being able to see the context. e.g. the paper could naturally be interested in studying a probability distribution with those properties, and proving the one you mention is the only possibility is interesting. Or, it may have already been clear from context exactly what probability distribution was meant, and now they are making that description because they're actually going to use those properties.

Comment: @Hurkyl, You're right, hadn't really thought about it that much. In that case, maybe the author proved/assumed some things about $X$ (like $E(X)=0$ and $E(X^2)=1$ and $-1\leq X\leq 1$), and then just uses $X$, without stating the obvious.

Comment: @Hurkyl : the authors don't really give a context, they just write, if $X$ is a symmetric random variable with these properties, yada, yada, yada. I suspect that maybe they didn't notice that those properties determine $X$ completely, which is a serious oversight.  If they did know that $X$ is a Rademacher random variable (see the answer I accepted), then I think describing it the way they did is very bad style (this is why I asked if probabilists do this all the time.  Batman's answer suggests that they don't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions that $-1 \leq X \leq 1$ and $E[X^2]$ are sufficient to characterize the random variable as being a Rademacher random variable (i.e. takes on values $\pm 1$ with equal probability), since if $X$ took values in $(-1,1)$ with positive measure, $E[X^2]$ would be strictly less than $1$.

They should have just called it a Rademacher random variable and moved on.

Edit: You also sometimes see the name "Symmetric Bernoulli".

Comment: That distribution has a *name*?!?!?!

Comment: Yes, its very commonly used in statistical learning theory/probability on banach spaces/concentration inequalities/empirical process theory for a technique known as "symmetrization". Also, look up Rademacher Complexity/Averages.